# Bad argument calling HTTPS site from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, wallet

I've oracle 11g R2 11.2.0.4.0 64 bit Standard edition one installed over linux centos 7, it work fine, Oracle Apex 20.2 is also installed and working fine.

I've added on my wallet the certifcate of of https://api.pagos360.com,   my problem is the error get when I call the site:

```
begin
  UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/path/to/wallet', '******');
end;


SELECT utl_http.request('https://api.pagos360.com') FROM dual;
```

When run the select statement I get the next error:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed 
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1720 ORA-28860: 
Error SSL fatal ORA-06512:  line 1
```

I also trie calling from apex procedure apex_web_service.make_rest_request but get similar error

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1339
ORA-29261: bad argument
ORA-06512: en "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1156
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-28860: Error SSL fatal
ORA-06512: en "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1346
ORA-06512: en "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line608
ORA-06512: en line38
```

I think that the problem is cause of my older oracle 11 version because if I test the same procedure on Oracle 19c it work fine.

Have you idea if there are any patch for this? or another via to solve.

regards